# Rewrite Delete Href link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been struggling with this rewrite rule for a few days, I have searched on here and tried many different rewrite rules I not sure what I am missing.

this is my PHP request to the database.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete'])){

    $ServerID = $_GET['delete'] ;

    $db = dbconnect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM servers WHERE ID = $ServerID");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

   }
?>
```

My HTML link that deletes the record for me

```
 <a href="servers.php?delete='.$ServerID.'">Delete</a>
```

and when you hover the above link it shows as follows

```
http://example.com/servers.php?delete=12
```

in my .htaccess I used the script to remove the .php at the end and used the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^servers/delete/(\d+)$ servers.php?delete=$1 [NC,L]
```

an then changed my HTML link to the following

```
<a href="servers/delete/'.$ServerID.'">Delete</a>
```

now when i hover the link i can see it rewrites the string to this

```
http://example.com/servers/delete/12
```

but when I click it it does not delete the record, it pulls up a URL like a page when all it should do is delete the record

Comment: And the error is which? Please note that the "server internal error" you see in the client (the browser) is not really helpful. The apache server refuses to hand out internal information for security reasons, that makes sense. Instead you need to check your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the actual issue is instead of having to guess. _You cannot implement or operate a web application without monitoring that log file!_

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews` - that is almost always the culprit, when you have partial overlaps between the “made up” URL (`servers`), and physically existing files (`servers.php`).

Comment: @arkascha the rewrite rule is incorrect i know that the problem it happen to me once before the error says Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: Is that te error you got from the error log file? Because many issues lead to that "internal server error" visible in the client... If it is the actual error from the log file then you have your answer: you created an endless rewriting loop.

Comment: Note that despite using prepared statements, you still have a SQL injection problem. Use `?` and pass $serverId to execute

Comment: @Evert injection problem on a delete function? never heard of that they you would need a input field for that and there is none its just a delete request

Comment: @Codifiy what if $ServerId contains the string `0 OR true`, it will delete every record in your table. You have to use parameterized queries for _anything_ that takes user input

Comment: You also _really_ shouldn't use GET request for breaking changes. Unsafe changes must be at least POST

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment to the question you learned from the http server's error log file that the actual issue is a rewriting loop you created by your rewriting rule.

The actual rule you implemented is perfectly fine. But you need to take care that it is only applied of the request does not already point to the rewrite target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /servers\.php$
RewriteRule ^servers/delete/(\d+)$ servers.php?delete=$1 [NC,L]
```

A much easier approach however would be to use the `END` flag instead of the older `L` flag in the rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^servers/delete/(\d+)$ servers.php?delete=$1 [NC,END]
```

See the documentation of the rewriting module to understand the difference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: it did nothing to delete the database record just takes it to a blank url with no error I refresh the db record is still there

Comment: I explained how to fix the issue with the rewriting loop. How to set up a working internal rewrite. I cannot say anything about your application logic, I am afraid. You will have to start debugging that yourself: consult your http server's error log file, since a "blank page" typically points towards an issue with your php script. Such errors are logged. _Again_ :  _You cannot implement or operate a web application without monitoring that log file! _ So what does that log file reveal what the issue is?

Comment: the url rewrite is working fine the problem is that it rewrites the url but does not delete anything from the database if i leave it servers.php?delete=12 it will delete from the database

Comment: So what did your debugging of your code show up? What is the issue? Where is the difference? As said: we cannot help with that, since we don't have your code... Did you check your error log file? How did you make sure that you are not looking at a cached result in your browser?